# How to merge variable names into a new variable name

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to work with objects and arrays for localization purposes. Now the issue is, that it requires a lot of coding to load the correct value from the objects 1-by-1.

As such, I tried to simplify the process by creating variable names out of other variables. Therefore I check for the `lang`-attribute and try to get that value as part of another variable name.

However, this does not work at all.

As example I could have an object `var text = { en: 'text', de: 'text' }`
I could make load the correct text by using:

```js
var language = document.documentElement.lang.toLowerCase();

switch (language) {
  case 'en':
    element.innerHTML = text.en;
    break;
  case 'de'
    element.innerHTML = text.de;
    break;
}
```

This will be really annoying to code so I tried to use following methodes instead:

```js
element.innerHTML = text.language;
element.innerHTML = `text.${language}`;
...
```

None of this works of course.

So I'm really in need of help to find a way to create a variable name by merging different variable names such as:

```
var a = 'text.';
var b = 'en';
var c = a.b; => text.en;
```

In the end, it must be recognized as a variable name and not as a string!

```js
var text = {
  en: 'Hello World',
  de: 'Hallo Welt',
  es: 'Hola Mundo',
  it: 'Ciao Mundo',
  fr: 'Bonjour Le Monde'
}

/* getting the language of the document */
var language = document.documentElement.lang.toLowerCase();

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var ele = document.body;
  /*does obviosly not work*/
  var content = `text.${language}`;
  ele.innerHTML = content;
  /*does work*/
  console.log(`the set language is: ${language}`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text[language]`

Comment: @Pointy that really solved it. I appreciate your comment and linking the duplicate. I was not able to find it with the terms I was searching for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const content = text[language]
```